# UICollectionView slow scrolling - creating cells

Tags: objective-c, uicollectionview

I am looking into collection view working on a project. My scrolling is ver slow for some reason, I think it's because I am doing a lot of processing in my cellForitemAtindex delegate method. Should I have UICollectionView create cells all at once rather then as it's scrolling? Or should can I cache the cells in some array on my own and then load from there as the user is scrolling? These are the only 2 I can think of, is there something else I can do? Thank you for your help.

Comment: have a look at the docs and see if there's a dequeueReusableCell mechanism as there is in UITableView.

Answer (score 1):

inside cell for item at index path you need to get a cell like this

```
UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cellID" forIndexPath:indexPath];
```

instead of making it from scratch. If you are using a custom subclass for the cell register it with the collection view by calling registerClass:forCellWithReuseIdentifier:\

You are not in charge of allocating, initializing or caching the reusable cells, the collection view does it for you.

Comment: This is how to handle dequeuing UICollectionViewCell objects. I have a project with 100's of cells, all with complex views in them, and the system does a great job of caching and displaying everything smoothly.  Most likely one of your views in your UICollectionViewCell is doing something computationally expensive (eg. displaying a 1000px x 1000px image). In the simulator turn on Color Blended Layers and look there first.  Then review all your code.  It'll be something you're doing within the cell.